# Array copying with compile flag -o3

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

When compiling the code below with gcc -o3 it takes around 50% longer time than without the "-o3".
What can be the reason for that?

```
const int stepsize = 2;
for (j = 0; j < NOOFITERATIONS; j++) {
  for(i=0; i < ROUND_DOWN(SOMEBIGSIZE, stepsize); i+=stepsize) {
      c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
      c[i+1] = a[i+1] + b[i+1];
  }
  for(; i < SOMEBIGSIZE; i++)
      c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Comment: Actually are you talking about **compilation time** or about **execution time** ?

Comment: @user1147851 are you asking about specific optimizations for array copy? Or is this a general question about optimization?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (all emphasis mine):

> Turning on optimization flags makes the compiler attempt to improve the performance and/or code size **at the expense of compilation time** and possibly the ability to debug the program. [...]
>
> Optimizing compilation **takes somewhat more time**, and a lot more memory
> for a large function.
>
> With -O, the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time, without performing any optimizations **that take a great deal of compilation time**.

This is completely expected behavior. Basically, your compiler needs to do more work for you, which increases the compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Optimize Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) -

> Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2 and also turns on the 
>   -finline-functions, -funswitch-loops, -fpredictive-commoning, -fgcse-after-reload, 
>   -ftree-loop-vectorize, -ftree-slp-vectorize, -fvect-cost-model, -ftree-partial-pre and 
>   -fipa-cp-clone options.

My assumption is those are expensive optimizations with your loops... especially the loop vectorize optimization.